# Extra margin in span tag?

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<span class="total white bold" style="background: #C2C555">TOTAL:</span>
<span style="background: #C2C555; margin: 0;">1 night</span>
<span class="cost">€ 120.00</span>
```

I expected the three spans would be together, but there is a space between them.

How to remove that space?

I'm using Chrome.

Regards

Javi

Comment: Can you please post your CSS also

Answer (score 8):

Remove the line-breaks, i.e.

```
<span class="total white bold" style="background: #C2C555">TOTAL:</span><span style="background: #C2C555; margin: 0;">1 night</span><span class="cost">€ 120.00</span>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LECBb/

Comment: That is very interesting. Why does a return add margin?

Comment: It isn't a margin. It is a space. All white space is normalised in HTML (except in pre elements, etc)

Comment: Spaces (whether single or multiple), tabs and carriage returns are all collapsed / shown as single spaces in HTML. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.1 for additional information.